# Salesforce trigger

Tags: apex, trigger

I am trying to create a trigger and need a bit of help

I have a situation where I have an account which is related to contact and to the asset. My data is coming into salesforce through integration.
Now the other scenario though my contact and asset are related when the data is populated onto the asset the contact lookup is not populated. So in another way they are not related though there is a lookup field on asset for contact.

The scenario would be simple if contact was linked to asset but it is not.
My company needs a report with all accounts along with asset details and details from contact for the asset.

I have 2 solutions:
1   Pre-populate fields on asset from contact. I tried doing URL hack which was not succesful as the data is coming into SFDC through integration so the button that I create would be no good.
So my question is please help me write a trigger to pre-populate fields from contact onto asset(name,email and phone no)

2  or pre-populate the lookup contact field on asset so the relationship is created.

I hope I have been able to explain properly.

Please can you help with this

Comment: A trigger won't "pre-populate", you can write a trigger so it will auto populate from `Contact` to `Asset`